# Searching for design pattern to handle multiple requests in pipeline

Tags: design-patterns

I'm searching for a design pattern for a specific pipeline process.
The service gets multiple requests that pass in pipeline, when each stage process all the requests at once and return the requests that fail in that stage.
In each stage every one of the requests can fail and end its way in that stage, but I want all the other requests that pass to continue to the next stage.

The final result will be:

1. The requests that pass all the stages.
2. The requests that fail in one of the stages, with the cause.

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably reach for a list of Eithers. Each stage could returns something like `[Either Error Success]`, e.g.:

```
[Left "Error foo",Right "request 1",Right "request 2",Left "Error bar",Right "request 3"]
```

You could then use e.g. [partitionEithers](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-Either.html#v:partitionEithers), which would give you:

```
(["Error foo","Error bar"],["request 1","request 2","request 3"])
```

You could then forward all the `Right` values to the next stage.

If you don't want to do it in Haskell, you can [Church-encode Either](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2018/06/11/church-encoded-either) in most languages.